# can I jump to specific frame of animation-list android?

Tags: android

I have an animation-list drawable with 100 frames, and its working fine. But now I want to jump to a specific frame and then start the animation from that frame. So is it possible in animation-list drawable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. There's no built-in way to do this. You're gonna have to create a separate animation which starts from whichever frame you need.

Comment: i have frames of a ball which is expanding, i want to handle the expansion of this ball with pinch in and pinch out, what will be the possible way to do this?

Comment: If you are doing physics based animations then they need to be reactive. Using static drawables is not the way to go here. You need to respond to touch events and dynamically change the dimensions of your view. You can have a look at the source code for Chris Banes' PhotoView (https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView) as a sample of how to resize views depending on touch events. This is not an easy task though and will take some effort.

Comment: PhotoView is using just one image, i have many images in which ball is expanding + changing its shape, that's why i was using animation-list, so is there anyother option for me?

Comment: The principles remain the same. You will have to choreograph the different images and their sizes according to user touch events. There is no ready made solution for such a thing but you can start working on it and post another question when you have some code ready.